# Border effect in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, borders, image-editing

I would like some help.

I am posting an image below, I need that kind of selection border effect

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before PS CS5, you had the extract filter (which was EPIC), then they decided to update it and mix it with the selection tools and "REFINE EDGE" came out, which needs a bit more work but you get even better results.

It's something long enough for not putting it here, but thanks to youtube... you can find a brilliant tutorial here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=soJdXsFx8V8&feature=youtu.be#aid=P9n5_Rj5c9Q

EDIT: If you want just to achieve the stroke effect around the girl, open the image in Illustrator first, draw a path around the wanted object and then play with the Dashed Line options. After that just copy paste the path into Photoshop as "Smart Object" and place it wherever needed. Here's an image from Illustrator:
[image]

Comment: i am not talking about the blend mode, the first pic of girl has selection borders all over, i want to know how to do that

Comment: Blend mode was just the very last of the answer but gotcha. Just take your photo into Adobe Illustrator, draw a path around the girl or object you want to use. Choose to color just the stroke (not the fill), select your stroke thickness from the stroke tool panel, at the very bottom you'll find a  "Dashed line" option, enable it and configure it as needed (normally you just fill the first to fields to get an even/balanced effect). After you get the desired style, copy paste it into Photoshop (select Smart Object when prompted), and voila...

Comment: Pleasure, I included this in the original answer with a small image so you could see how it's done.